# Creating an AMI from instance store - How to find where instance store is mounted?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to create an AMI from an "instance store" instance on amazon EC2. This is what I did

1. Took an existing fedora ami from community-  ami-72bf441b
2. Launched the system and made some modifications
3. Now I am trying to create an ami for the newly launched system using http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-snapshot-s3-linux.html
4. Reached the point where I need to copy cert key
   "Copy your Amazon EC2 private key and X.509 certificate to the directory where an instance store is mounted using a secure copy function such as SCP."

Here I am stuck as to how can find the directory where instance store is mounted? The documentation says /media/ephemeral0 or /dev/sdf, but no such directories are present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically on an instance store AMI almost all directories are ephemeral. Perhaps they mean, you should not copy to an manually attached EBS or network filesystems. Not sure. Anyways, I find [this howto](http://robpickering.com/2010/07/create-a-full-backup-image-of-your-amazon-ec2-instance-2-129) easier to follow.

Whatever howto you use make sure the resulting AMI does NOT contain your certificate and key for obvious security reasons. You may need to use the -e flag.